# Nested Angular Ng-Repeat Performance

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an odd ng-repeat problem related to performance (or at least I believe it's ng-repeat related). I have a list of items that will never be more than 10 or so, but this problem occurs regardless of how many items there are (even when there's only one).

When the page first loads, it's lightning fast. I can even add/update items in the list and it still happens nearly instantaneously. But as soon as I try to remove an item, it takes > 4 seconds. Let me show a couple piece of code.

```
removeItem(itemId) {
  this.ordersService.removeItem(
    this.order.order_id,
    itemId
  ).then(
    (item) => {
      let index = _.findIndex(this.items, {
        item_id: itemId
      });
      this.items.splice(index, 1);

      console.log('item removed');

      this.$timeout(function() {
        console.log('$timeout fired');
      });
    }, (response) => {
      this.message = response.data.message;
    }
  );
}
```

`Template`:

```
<li ng-click="OrderCtrl.removeItem(item.item_id)"
    ng-repeat="item in OrderCtrl.items track by item.item_id">

    <div class="row-wrapper">
        <span class="field">{{ item.item_number }}
        </span><span class="field">{{ item.model_number }}
        </span><span class="field">{{ item.model_title }}</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

This obviously doesn't run in it's current state, but I think you get the picture. When the row is clicked, it calls the `removeItem` method on the `OrderCtrl`. The controller fires off an Ajax request from the service, which completes in about 80ms. Both "item removed" and "$timeout fired" are displayed in my console nearly instantaneously. However it takes about 4 seconds to actually visually remove the rendered element from the list.

Is there anything here that stands out to somebody that I should be doing? I'm about out of ideas. Is it something with the `this.items.splice` that affects the watches in some weird way or something?

Comment: does the list need to be translated or anything else that might change values in the list? if not maybe you can use one time bindings for other items in the ng-repeat (item in ::OrderCtrl.items track by item.item_id)

Comment: Possibly a problem where you need to explicitly call $scope.$apply in the 'then' function of your promise?

Comment: @ChasBrown Not a bad idea. I thought of that myself and got the error where the digest is already running, though.

Comment: @alphapilgrim The actual app is quite a bit more complicated than this. I stripped out a bunch of stuff just to rule out other causes for the latency. But there are actually other actions that change model numbers, of individual items, etc.

Comment: Since you tried .apply and got the error, might be worth trying .digest or $applyAsync([exp]);